# GCP Cloud Function works, but gives errors

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud function which works on my local machine but when I put it live on GCP Cloud Functions I get errors and it crashes. But the data that is mean to be used and collected is done so according to the logs.

The code and errors from the logs are below:

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore

db = firestore.Client(project='xxxxxxxx')

# API INFO
Base_url = 'https://xxxxxxxx/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2'
Sport_id = '1000093204'
AppID = 'xxxxxxxx'
AppKey = 'xxxxxxxx'
Country = 'en_AU'
Site = 'www.xxxxxxxx.com.au'

project_id = "xxxxxxxx"
subscription_id = "xxxxxxx_au_basketball_nba_events"
# Number of seconds the subscriber should listen for messages
timeout = 5.0

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
# The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_id}`
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

def callback(message):
    # print(message.data)

    event_ids = json.loads(message.data)
    events = event_ids.strip('][').split(', ')

    print(events)

    url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{','.join(map(str, events))}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}"
    print(url)

    windata = requests.get(url).text
    windata = json.loads(windata)

    for odds_data in windata['betOffers']:
        if odds_data['betOfferType']['name'] == 'Head to Head' and 'MAIN' in odds_data['tags']:
            event_id = odds_data['eventId']
            home_team = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['participant']
            home_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][0]['odds']
            away_team = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['participant']
            away_team_win_odds = odds_data['outcomes'][1]['odds']

            print(f'{event_id} {home_team} {home_team_win_odds} {away_team} {away_team_win_odds}')

            # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'unibet_au').document(u'basketball_nba').collection(u'win_odds').document(
                f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'home_team': home_team,
                u'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
                u'away_team': away_team,
                u'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
            })


streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber:
    try:
            # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
            # unless an exception is encountered first.
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```

Output in Pycharm console (correct)

```
['1018936430', '1018936341', '1018936411', '1018936397', '1018936472', '1018936410', '1018936333', '1018936326', '1018936349', '1018936381', '1018936393']
https://xxxxxxxxx/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2/betoffer/event/1018936430,1018936341,1018936411,1018936397,1018936472,1018936410,1018936333,1018936326,1018936349,1018936381,1018936393.json?app_id=21e03bb8&app_key=c0191eaf354cc07bc3769817b8c1acd0&local=en_AU&site=www.xxxx.com.au
1018936397 New York Knicks 1790 Atlanta Hawks 2070
1018936472 Chicago Bulls 1550 Charlotte Hornets 2550
1018936349 Dallas Mavericks 1420 Utah Jazz 2950
1018936411 Miami Heat 1400 Sacramento Kings 3050
1018936430 Philadelphia 76ers 1450 Washington Wizards 2850
1018936410 Houston Rockets 2850 Los Angeles Clippers 1450
1018936333 Milwaukee Bucks 1150 Detroit Pistons 5600
1018936381 Portland Trail Blazers 2550 Memphis Grizzlies 1540
1018936393 Los Angeles Lakers 2250 New Orleans Pelicans 1670
1018936341 Cleveland Cavaliers 2050 Boston Celtics 1790
1018936326 San Antonio Spurs 3350 Toronto Raptors 1340
```

PubSub message body

```
"[1018936430, 1018936341, 1018936411, 1018936397, 1018936472, 1018936410, 1018936333, 1018936326, 1018936349, 1018936381, 1018936393]"
```

when this function is setup on GCP Cloud Functions I get the following error when its run

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'`

The function also crashes but the logs say that the function is executed and all the data is collected and stored but I get these errors

from the logs:

`ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]`

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'`

`Function execution took 6205 ms. Finished with status: crash`

Comment: Your problem is with this line `events = event_ids.strip('][').split(', ')`. You are trying to treat a dictionary as a string. Dictionaries do not have the method `strip()` or `split()`.  Edit your question with what you are trying to accomplish with that line of code.

Comment: I am trying to strip the formatting of the pubsub message `"[1018936430, 1018936341, 1018936411, 1018936397, 1018936472, 1018936410, 1018936333, 1018936326, 1018936349, 1018936381, 1018936393]"` so that i can use the IDs in an API URL which will look something like this `https://xxxxxxxxx/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2/betoffer/event/1018936430,1018936341,1018936411,1018936397,1018936472,1018936410,1018936333,1018936326,1018936349,1018936381,1018936393.json?app_id=21e03bb8&app_key=c0191eaf354cc07bc3769817b8c1acd0&local=en_AU&site=www.xxxx.com.au`

Comment: Are you using Gen1 or Gen2 of Cloud Functions?

Comment: Gen1 python 3.10

Comment: You write your code as you write a background process. It can't work because you don't comply with the Cloud Functions contract: You have to handle HTTP request, you can't pull a PubSub subscription. Use a push subscription instead

Comment: so you would recommend:
**Function 1 (push)** - this function collects game IDS (would this be a http trigger type? or PubSub trigger)
**Function 2 (pull)**- this function with use game IDs supplied in pub/sub message from function 1 (would this be a http trigger type? or PubSub trigger)
**Function 3(pull)** - this function with use game IDs supplied in pub/sub message from function 1 (would this be a http trigger type? or PubSub trigger)